# Mails with attachments through vba macro

Tags: vba, excel, email

I am running a macro for sending mails to multiple recipients via Outlook with one or more attachments through vba excel. I am not well versed in macros and hence took some inputs from various sources and came upon the below final code.

However I have mentioned max. limit of 3 file attachments which is constant for all recipients but have to disable by commenting whenever I have to attach only 1 or 2 files accordingly like e.g in the below code I have disabled the 2nd and 3rd attachment columns for attaching 1 file across. 
Is there any way where the macro would automatically take the inputs according to the values entered and left blank e.g If one recipient has 1 attachment and the next recipient has 2 or 3 attachments

```
Sub SendMail()

    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    For Each cell In ws.Range("A2:A1000")

        Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

        With objMail
            .To = cell.Value
            .Cc = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            .Bcc = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
            .Subject = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
            .Body = cell.Offset(0, 4).Value
            .Attachments.Add cell.Offset(0, 5).Value
            '.Attachments.Add cell.Offset(0, 6).Value
            '.Attachments.Add cell.Offset(0, 7).Value
            .Send
        End With

        Set objMail = Nothing
    Next cell

    Set ws = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: You may want to add some wait time, a second or two, after sending a mail. Sometimes it's too fast for outlook to send so many mails.

Comment: @EganWolf - Well I haven't faced any issue as such regarding time to send. Takes hardly 2 secs to mail 40 recipients. Let me know if I need to add something?

Comment: Actually, I have never tested that. I was using and updating a macro written by somebody else that was sending about 30 mails with attachment and there was a comment, that sometimes error occurs without sleep time.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim i As Long, c As Range
'....
With objMail
    .To = cell.Value
    .Cc = cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
    .Bcc = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value
    .Subject = cell.Offset(0, 3).Value
    .Body = cell.Offset(0, 4).Value
    For i = 5 to 6
        Set c = cell.Offset(0, i)
        If c.Value <> "" Then .Attachments.Add c.Value
    Next i
    .Send
End With
'....
```

Comment: You used `With` inside `With` and I'm quite sure that VBA will not know how to read `.Attachments.Add .Value`.

Comment: Works great! Thank you @TimWilliams,  Thanks a lot both for your inputs. Well a tiny issue - The mails get sent before encountering an error

Microsoft Visual Basic 
Run-time error '-214746729 (80004005)': 
We need to know who to send this to. Make sure you enter at least 
one name.

Comment: Figured it out, has something to do with MS Office version updates. Thanks again for the solution. Cheers, have a great day :)